# jQuery - Function still running on element after class removed

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I've have some code that switches between a toggle menu and a dropdown menu depending on the window size. It works but a function that should only be run on the ul.dropdown is being run on ul.toggle too.

Resize the panel to toggle the two menu states. When in toggle mode the sub level uls and going up and down which they shouldn't be.

http://jsfiddle.net/agileapricot/C8ZRC/

Answer (score 2):

The hover event is attached to the aaDropdown element when the page is loaded. At a later time, you remove the class which matched the selector, but do not remove the attached hover event. This causes the binding with hover to still be fired.

The avoid this, either:

1. remove and reattach the hover listener in your aaMenuMode
   function, or:
2. use live() to dynamically evaluate elements matching your selector (preferred)

Comment: +1 for suggesting live(); this is a classic scenario for using it.

Comment: Thank you.I've updated the jsFiddle to use .live but it's not working as expected. Any chance someone could point out what've done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please use `var aaDropdown = jQuery(".dropdown li").has("ul"); // Cache dropdowns`
instead of `var aaDropdown = jQuery("ul.dropdown li").has("ul"); // Cache dropdowns`

and making a jsFiddle of your code and placing the link here would get you better responses.

Comment: Done and done. I'm guessing dropping the ul is better for performance?

Answer (score 0):

You can also unbind the event using the `.unbind()` method
http://api.jquery.com/unbind/